# Sequelize findall search

Tags: sequelize.js

```
Country.hasMany(City, { foreignKey: 'country_id' });
City.belongsTo(Country, { foreignKey: 'country_id' });
City.hasMany(Walk, { foreignKey: 'city_id' });
Walk.belongsTo(City, { foreignKey: 'city_id' });
Walk.hasMany(Point, { foreignKey: 'walk_id' });
```

Query field:

```
walks: Db.models.dl_walk.findAll({
    where: {
        $or: [
            {
                name: { like: `%${args.search}%` }
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

When `search="NameCountry"`, how get current country and all "walks"
in current country?

Answer (score 0):

To find all the walks belonging to a country, You would need to make a query with association
Something like

```
Model.Country.findAll({where:/*some criteria*/, 
  include:[{model: Model.city, include: model.walk}]
})
```

This would make a join query starting from country to walks